# How to compute cost of Google API calls?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-cloud-platform

Like everyone else, I received an email saying that I need to activate billing to continue using the Google Maps API, and so I did. Now I try to understand what the cost my API usage will be – and I’m lost.
On Google Cloud Platform API / API and services I can see that there are 1 635 Maps Elevation API calls and 1157 Maps Java Script API calls at noon today.
At the same time, under IAM and administration / Quotas  I see : 123 / 2500 requests per day.

What is the relation between the 1635+1157 API calls and the 123 requests?

I used 63 842 Elevation API calls and 36 023 Maps Java Script calls during the last 30 days – according to the price sheet [google cloud price sheet](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet).
 This would cost `63842*5/1000+36023/1000*7 $ = 571` $ - yet the price shown is $0 for now. 
It’s a free website - if I have to pay this kind of money it will be down next month…

Sorry if this is not the right place to ask, but I do this as a hobby. Thanks.

Comment: considering we're working with a lot of money here (for a hobbyist site) it's best to contact google directly as well. Users on StackOverflow **can** be wrong and it's best to not take the risk to only rely on one site.

Comment: Idk how you calculated that but this is wrong. What about your free monthly quota?

Comment: https://mapsplatformtransition.withgoogle.com/calculator

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about programming.

Comment: You can file a support case directly with Google via https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Comment: Xomena : If you follow this link for elevation API, Google suggests to post the question on stackoverflow. That’s here, right ? :-) MrUpsidDown : You are right, I didn’t deduce the free quota, but even 571 – 200 * is too much for a free site, it doesn’t change the problem. The calculator confirms my figures, but there is still the incoherence between the requests / day in the quota section of the console (basically it says I have lots calls left). Thanks to all who tried to help even if this is not exactly a programming question. Sorry if I bothered anyone with my first question on this site.

Comment: @Ted Reinhard There are two blocks: one for community support and another one to file case with Google support. I agree the titles are confusing and not clear. You should use link in the right block to speak with Google support. I'm afraid the community cannot help with billing questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little summary, now that the new cost scheme is in effect:

1. The  Google Cloud Platform API / API and services section is the reference for computing API usage cost
2. The IAM and administration / Quotas section ‘may take more time to update’ (according to Google support) and was off by a factor of 10 in my  case. I could never figure out the details (maybe something about the time zone ?), but I understand that you are not supposed to use it to check usage on a daily basis (use 1. For that)
3. Even if the mail from Google says API usage will ‘probably continue to be free’ in your case, now is a good time to check (half way through the first month): in my case, the actual cost would have roughly been 500 $ (-$ 200 free offer).

My solution to the problem on my free website was to remove the google maps from it. :-(

Thanks to all who tried to help.